# Too Many versions of python on my computer

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, module

I have too many versions of python on my computer. And, when I try to run my code, my module like pandas, selenium, etc said this error message:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'.

I have pip and conda install everything but neither version of python works when I choose each of them in VS Code interpreter.

Do you have a solution to uninstall each version of python?

Command prompt: [image: screenshot]

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the versions of python

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.7 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.6 2
```

Then you need to choose which version should be defined as default

```
sudo update-alternatives --set python /usr/bin/python3.6
```

Alternatively, try [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) pyenv to manage your python versions.

Answer (score 0):

just type Apps and Features in you pc's search bar and uninstall every version of python you see there and re install the one that you need

Answer (score 0):

@Sagar mochi.  Thanks for your answer.  I have been searching for and trying different solutions all day.  Your solution worked for me :)